# FFMPEG Calculate Hash After Encoding Before Writing

Tags: ffmpeg

I am experimenting with losslessly compressing some raw video.  How can I perform a frame hash on the encoded output *before or while* writing it to the file system?  I want to make an `original.hashes` and a `compressed.hashes`.  (I will compare them with another tool later.)

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -start_number 0 -i "%IMAGES_DIRECTORY%\%%03d.png" ^
-filter_complex "split=3 [copyHash] [copyLossless] [otherIn]; [otherIn] {some filter here} [otherOut]" ^
-map [copyLossless] -c:v libx264rgb -qp 0 -pix_fmt rgb24 "%IMAGES_DIRECTORY%\lossless.avi" ^
-map [copyHash] -f framehash -hash SHA512 "%IMAGES_DIRECTORY%\original.hashes" ^
-map [otherOut] {some other encoding} someOtherFile.idc

ffmpeg -start_number 0 -i "%IMAGES_DIRECTORY%\lossless.avi" -pix_fmt rgb24 -f framehash -hash SHA512  "%IMAGES_DIRECTORY%\decoded.hashes"

comp original.hashes decoded.hashes
```

So above, I would like to avoid the second call to ffmpeg.  Like if I could split the `lossless.avi` output of the first call to two new streams:  One to the file system and one to a demuxer feeding the hash muxer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a nitpick: you don't want to compute hashes on the *encoded* frame data before or while writing. You're testing the fidelity of the  lossless encoding so you need to compare the *decoded* frame of the x264 encode with the corresponding PNG.

So, first here's how to do what you specifically asked for.

Use the tee pseudo-muxer

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -start_number 0 -i "%IMAGES_DIRECTORY%\%%03d.png" ^
-filter_complex "[0]{some filter here}[otherOut]" ^
-map 0 -c:v libx264rgb -qp 0 -pix_fmt rgb24 -f tee "%IMAGES_DIRECTORY%\lossless.avi|[f=avi]pipe:" ^
-map 0 -f framehash -hash SHA512 "%IMAGES_DIRECTORY%\original.hashes" ^
-map [otherOut] {some other encoding} someOtherFile.idc | ffmpeg -f avi -i - -f framehash -hash SHA512 %IMAGES_DIRECTORY%\decoded.hashes"
```

---

If your end goal is to check the fidelity of the lossless encoding, use

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -start_number 0 -i "%IMAGES_DIRECTORY%\%%03d.png" ^
-filter_complex "[0]{some filter here}[otherOut]" ^
-map 0 -c:v libx264rgb -qp 0 -pix_fmt rgb24 "%IMAGES_DIRECTORY%\lossless.avi" ^
-map [otherOut] {some other encoding} someOtherFile.idc
```

and then

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -start_number 0 -i "%IMAGES_DIRECTORY%\%%03d.png" -i lossless.avi ^
-filter_complex "ssim" -f null -
```

If the result is lossless, the readout will say

```
SSIM R:1.000000 (inf) G:1.000000 (inf) B:1.000000 (inf) All:1.000000 (inf)
```

Comment: This answer made so many different things click for me (`hash` doesn't use raw input, `-map 0` instead of `split`, and that's what a tee is for).  Thanks!  But it doesn't avoid the problem of reading lossless.avi off of the disk to decode/compare it.  In fact, you are also reading the original images off of the disk twice to compare them to the decoded image.

Comment: Is there no way to take encoded packets and fork them to a muxer and a decoder in the same FFMPEG instance?

Comment: No. Encoding occurs after decoding (and filtering), so that provision isn't there. Looks like you are concerned about disk I/O. What you could do is pipe lossless avi to another ffmpeg instance which computes hashes.

Comment: I've edited my first command, so that the AVI output is simultaneously piped to another ffmpeg instance which then computes hashes on the *decoded* frames.

Comment: And here I was looking up how to split outputs on the Windows command line.  (To send the `lossless.avi` to a file and a pipe.  Ugh.)  This much better, thanks!  The only issue was the output filename in the `tee` needed to be surrounded in single quotes.  Also, I'm not sure that I like SSIM, as it is much more computationally complex than a hash and the output is subject to rounding errors.  I'll do a quick performance comparison, but the ideal solution is to just do a bit-for-bit comparison as both streams are flowing through memory... but a hash is close enough.